# Anti-virus to scan single files?

Tags: windows, macos, anti-virus

What's the best AV available if you just wish to scan single files after download and not wreak havoc constantly on your OS?

Suggestions for both Windows and Mac OS X would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could define "best".

Comment: @jzd  It'd help if you answered giving different possible definitions of best that you have in mind, and your answers for each, thus giving an answer that's useful to more people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site will virus scan one file.
http://www.virustotal.com/

I don't know if it scans for signatures of non windows OS viruses. But you can of course use it from any OS. Just submit the file to the site and it gets scanned automatically.

Comment: Too bad it has a maximum file size of 20MB.

Comment: Really any anti virus can  integrate with the shell and scan individual files with a right click and scan.  If by havoc you mean the virus itself playing havoc, then it won't lest you run it, so you can just scan it. If you mean the anti virus playing havoc.. well, it'll probably be a small one so avira or avast or if you pay then NOD.

Comment: http://www.urlvoid.com/ to scan a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I use both Microsoft Security Essentials and Malwarebytes, both with a right-click.